# Stripe.h file not found

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the Stripe SDK in my iOS App but there seems to be a problem. Whenever I try to import it like this:

```
#import "Stripe.h"
```

I get the following error:

```
Stripe.h file not found
```

But I have the file right here:

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Abdullah Shafique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folders are blue in Xcode, indicating that the folders themselves have been added as resources, rather than the source files within them. You should remove the stripe-ios folder from your project, and re-add it, ensuring that you choose the option to "Make groups for any added folders"; this will ensure each source file is added to your project, rather than the folder being added to your resources.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate what the problem is, but I guess the .h file is just in the wrong directory...

So, find a .h file in your project that you CAN import. In which directory is this file?

In which directory is the Stripe.h file? Is it even in a subdirectory of the project root?

Answer (score 1):

In your bridging header file use this statement as it is `#import <Stripe/Stripe.h>` . If it does not work, clean your project several times, I had the same error and nothing else worked except what I specified above.